# Does Independence of Conditional Expectation still hold without multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Suppose that X,$Z_1 ... Z_n$ have a multivariate  normal distribution, and X has zero mean. Furthermore, suppose that $Z_1 ... Z_n$ are independent. Show that

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Z_1 ... Z_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X|Z_i]$$

Is this result true without the multivariate normal condition? Prove or give a counter example.

I am able to show the first part where the multivariate normal condition is used. I am however unsure about the result without the multivariate normal condition.

Comment: Take $X=Z_1Z_2\cdots Z_n$ for a counter-example. [Here $Z_i$'s are independent with mean $0$].

Comment: Hi do you mind expanding on your example.

Comment: LHS becomes $X$ and RHS becomes $0$.  You would be able to prove these if you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n=2$, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ i.i.d. with standard normal distribution and
$$
X=\left(\mathbf{1}_{Z_1>0}-\mathbf{1}_{Z_1\leqslant 0}\right)Z_2.
$$
Then $X$ has a standard normal distribution, $(X,Z_1,Z_2)$ is not a Gaussian vector, $\mathbb E\left[X\mid Z_1\right]=\mathbb E\left[X\mid Z_2\right]=0$ but $\mathbb E\left[X\mid Z_1,Z_2\right]=X$.

This example is inspired from one of the most classical one providing a non-Gaussian vector whose marginals are Gaussian.